# RODBC - Value does not fit into a numeric

Tags: sql, r, odbc, netezza

Hello and thanks in advance.  I have an ODBC connection to a Netezza database using `RODBC` and I'm trying to write a data frame to a database table.  I keep getting the following error:

```
HY000 46 ERROR:  Numeric overflow.  Value does not fit in a numeric(10,10)
```

Which I don't understand how I'm getting it because all my numeric values are rounded to the nearest digit!  I have my SQL query where I created the table and my R code below with a sample of what I'm trying to write to the database:

## SQL Code

```
                CREATE TABLE R_FORECAST
                (
                          ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
                          NUMBER CHARACTER(7) NOT NULL,
                          ITEM_NO INTEGER NOT NULL,
                          ITEM_DESC VARCHAR(50),
                          FORECASTDATE DATE NOT NULL,
                          MEANFORECAST NUMERIC(10,10),
                          UPPER50 NUMERIC(10,10),
                          UPPER75 NUMERIC(10,10),
                          UPPER90 NUMERIC(10,10),
                          LOWER50 NUMERIC(10,10),
                          LOWER75 NUMERIC(10,10),
                          LOWER90 NUMERIC(10,10),
                          CREATED_DT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT "TIMESTAMP"(now(0)::"VARCHAR"),
                          TRANSACTION_DT DATE NOT NULL
                )
                DISTRIBUTE ON (ID);
```

## R Code

```
    loadprod <- odbcConnect(dsn="dsn", uid = "uid", pwd = "pwd",case="nochange", colQuote=c() )
    
    head(FORECAST)
    
        TRANSACTION_DT  ID  NUMBER  ITEM_NO ITEM_DESC   FORECASTDATE    MEANFORECAST    UPPER50 UPPER75 UPPER90 LOWER50 LOWER75 LOWER90 CREATED_DT
        1/26/2015   4192    2239    9664    DESC    2/16/2015   11  13  17  22  9   7   2   1/26/2015 16:38
        1/26/2015   4192    2239    9664    DESC    2/17/2015   14  16  19  24  11  10  7   1/26/2015 16:38
        1/26/2015   4192    2239    9664    DESC    2/18/2015   13  15  18  21  10  9   6   1/26/2015 16:38
        1/26/2015   4192    2239    9664    DESC    2/19/2015   13  15  18  24  10  8   6   1/26/2015 16:38
        1/26/2015   4192    2239    9664    DESC    2/20/2015   15  18  21  26  13  11  9   1/26/2015 16:38
        1/26/2015   4192    2239    9664    DESC    2/21/2015   13  16  19  24  11  9   7   1/26/2015 16:38

sqlSave(loadprod, FORECAST, tablename = "R_FORECAST", append = T,
            rownames = F, colnames = FALSE, verbose = T,
            safer = TRUE, addPK = FALSE, 
            varTypes <- tmp$TYPE_NAME,
            fast = TRUE, test = FALSE, nastring = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUMERIC(10,10) will only hold values less than 1. The first values in the type definition of NUMERIC is the precision, which is the total number of digits stored, and the second value is the scale, which is how many of those digits are after the decimal point.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table numeric_test (col1 numeric(10,10), col2 numeric(10,0));
CREATE TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into numeric_test values (0.1234567890, 1234567890);
INSERT 0 1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from numeric_test;
     COL1     |    COL2
--------------+------------
 0.1234567890 | 1234567890
(1 row)
```

If you try to insert anything that would require a digit to the left of the decimal point into COL1, you will get the error you are experiencing.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into numeric_test values (10, 11);
ERROR:  Numeric overflow.  Value does not fit in a numeric(10,10)
```

If what you are looking for is to store integer values, you generally should be using INTEGER instead of NUMERIC. This provides a number of benefits including generally better storage efficiency and support for zone maps.

Comment: It seems so simple now!  Once I changed the values to (10,0) it worked! Thanks a lot!